# In VBA, how do I select a value in the drop down box to determine the sheet the data is pulled?

Tags: excel, vba

I am simply trying to pull data from a spreadsheet that has three different Sheets into a separate spreadsheet.  I created a drop down box with the names of the three sheets available so the user can first select the sheet their information is in then run the macro pulling in the respective information.

How can I create an if then statement so that if the drop down box shows Sheet1 for example it looks in that Sheet1 for the information and same for Sheet2 and Sheet3?

Comment: Add a little more context, and examples of what you have tried

Comment: As aledustet says, show us what you've got.  For example, is your drop down a control, or a cell with a validation list?  the short answer is "dim sh as worksheet, set sh = sheets (myselection), do stuff to sh"

Comment: i think that `Select Case` will be better for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it;

```
=IF(A1="Sheet1",Sheet1!B3,IF(A1="Sheet2",Sheet2!B3,IF(A1="Sheet3",Sheet3!B3,"")))
```

If you have a sheet called "Sheet0" that contains a drop down selection in cell A1 so that cell value can be either "Sheet1", "Sheet2" or "Sheet3" and all cells on "Sheet0" that need to display data from either sheet1,2 or 3 have this formula in, it will work. My example show it pulling in data from cell B3 on either of the three sheets but you will just need to edit it accordingly. It's just an extended IF formula, with another IF formula in the negative result of the previous one. I hope that makes sense. It works my explanation may be bad.